# How to make textarea element fill the whole parent div grid box (using angular-gridster2 or gridster library)?

Tags: html, css, angular, gridster

I am using this grid library: https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2
What I want to do is put a textarea inside of a box in the grid. I tried putting

```
style="width:100%;
height:100%;
border-box:100%;
-moz-border-box:100%;
-webkit-border-box:100%"
```

on the textarea, though it does not appear to fill the whole space.

Can someone show me how I can make it so that I can get that textarea to fill the whole space of the parent div? (grid box) without having to be explicit like: `height:300px` as an example.

Plunkr of my issue:
https://plnkr.co/edit/CFSzKIPEEdsB28MjZEkw?p=preview

Notice how the textareas don't fill the whole box.

Comment: Can you provide an example that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I just used the default example they had and stuck a textbox in one of the boxes.

Comment: All works well for me https://plnkr.co/edit/XOzosc2rpf9QI3Y8vjp1?p=preview

Comment: Nice try, but you can't edit any of the textboxes. From what I know about this library, you need a <div class="gridster-item-content"></div> to be able to have editable content in box so that you can have selectable/editable content. I've  updated OP and your Plunkr with what I am seeing. https://plnkr.co/edit/CFSzKIPEEdsB28MjZEkw?p=preview

Comment: Click right button of mouse

Comment: @yurzui I dont want to perform any action for the textbox to fit

Comment: Ok, try my updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/CK5NPGfBT5b2QnzGIiX2?p=preview

Comment: @Rolando upvote too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the styles for this class `gridster-item-content`

```
.gridster-item-content{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

[**Updated Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/n9rwgq4OoVERNyoW16rg?p=preview)